# Command git push origin master not working

Tags: git

I have successfully connected to github through ssh as the following commands demonstrate.

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:.ssh bobsmith$ ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts.
Hi bobsmith76! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

However when I cd to the folder which has the .git files and run

```
git push origin master
```

I get

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/bobsmith/git_learn.git/'
```

When I vist
https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
I don't really see anything very understabable about what I am supposed to do. I do see

> will require the use of token-based authentication, such as a personal access token (for developers) or an OAuth or GitHub App installation token (for integrators) for all authenticated Git operations on GitHub.com. You may also continue using SSH keys where you prefer.

But I thought I had successfully used an ssh key.

Comment: What is the question? You can check whether origin is an ssh or an https remote by checking the url for the remote with git remote get-url origin

Comment: Did you add the ssh key in GitHub web interface? Or, more broadly, did you follow the guide: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: @mbojko: he has the ssh key installed *on* GitHub, and `ssh -Tv git@github.com` (or `ssh -T`, the `v` is just to watch ssh at work) is using it. But *Git* isn't using it because he's still telling Git to push via https rather than ssh. (It's still a good idea to consult the GitHub docs of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still trying to push via `https`, instead of `ssh` so it tries to authenticate via `https`.

Select the `ssh`-Tab from the `Code`-Button inside your `github`-repository, and change the url of the local `git` repository with the following command.

```
git remote set-url origin <git-url>
```

The url should look like this:

```
git@github.com:<User>/<Repo>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.